# How do I query every person that does not know anyone that takes classes?

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with the following SQL problem:
I must query all persons that do not know anyone who takes classes, using the following tables:

```
╔═════════╦════════╦═══════════╦═════╗
║ Persons ║        ║           ║     ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═══════════╬═════╣
║ id      ║ name   ║ address   ║ age ║
║ 1       ║ Teddy  ║ Utrecht   ║ 96  ║
║ 2       ║ Harun  ║ Texas     ║ 64  ║
║ 3       ║ Egbert ║ Rome      ║ 68  ║
║ 4       ║ John   ║ Amsterdam ║ 39  ║
╚═════════╩════════╩═══════════╩═════╝
╔═══════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ Knows ║            ║            ║
╠═══════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ id    ║ personA_id ║ personB_id ║
║ 25    ║ 1          ║ 2          ║
║ 26    ║ 1          ║ 3          ║
║ 27    ║ 3          ║ 2          ║
║ 28    ║ 3          ║ 4          ║
╚═══════╩════════════╩════════════╝
╔══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ TakesClasses ║           ║          ║
╠══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ id           ║ person_id ║ class_id ║
║ 35           ║ 1         ║ 50       ║
║ 36           ║ 1         ║ 51       ║
║ 37           ║ 1         ║ 52       ║
║ 38           ║ 1         ║ 53       ║
║ 39           ║ 2         ║ 54       ║
║ 40           ║ 2         ║ 55       ║
║ 41           ║ 2         ║ 56       ║
╚══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

After a long time trying different queries, the following query is the closest I got to the desired result:

```
select distinct name 
from Persons P
where P.id NOT IN 
(select person_id 
 from TakesClasses T join Knows K 
 on T.person_id = K.personA_id
 where class_id IS NOT NULL)
```

I seem to get more results back than is necessary for this query (Harun, Egbert and John), but I cannot find the mistake I'm making. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Don't store age. Most people tend to become older ever year, and your data will soon become out-of-date. Store date/year of birth instead.

Comment: I believe that `(select person_id` should be `(select personB_id`, however, the knows table should be symetric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
select P.id, name 
from Persons P
where P.id NOT IN 
(select K.personA_id
from TakeClasses T join Knows K 
on T.person_id = K.personB_id
)
```

Comment: This did not solve it unfortunately. I still receive too many results in the output. I need the persons that do not know anyone who takes classes.

Comment: check out my query, I just Edited, I think it works now

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem suggests `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from persons p
where not exists (select 1
                  from takesclasses tc join
                       knows k
                       on tc.personB_id = k.person_id
                  where k.personA_id = p.id
                 );
```

The correlation clause connects the subquery to the outer query.

Note that this assumes that the `knows` relationship is symmetric.  So if A "knows" B then B "knows" A is also in the table.

EDIT:

I *strongly* advise you never to use `NOT IN` with subqueries.  It does not behave as expected if *any* values returned in the subquery are `NULL`.  In this case, though, you can do:

```
select p.*
from persons p
where p.id not in (select k.personA_id
                   from takesclasses tc join
                        knows k
                        on tc.personB_id = k.person_id
                  );
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficent to take the person id directly from the `takesclasses` table as a distinct? And then join Persons to get the name? The assumption would be that there are less persons taking classes than the amount of persons in total (i.e. someone would not take any class).

Comment: @ChatterOne . . . The `name` is not in the `takesclasses` table, so you need a `join` to `persons`.  Plus, `select distinct` is an expensive operation, so I like to avoid it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said `And then join Persons to get the name`. But if you want to avoid a distinct there's no alternative.

Comment: I must use a NOT IN statement for this exercise. Your solution gives the proper output though. Thanks for that. Do you have a suggestion for this query using NOT IN? :)

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation :)